# SQL ERROR 5172 : PAGEAUDIT PROPERTY IS INCORRECT

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am try to execute below query through ADO.NET i.e. ExecuteNoQuery from Windows Application:

```
CREATE DATABASE TESTDATABASE ON (NAME=TESTDATABASE, FILENAME='C:\Test\TEST.mdf', SIZE=4MB, FILEGROWTH=4MB) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

In Production, most of the times it works, but rarely fails with below error and we are not able to reproduce:

> ERROR: "The header for file 'C:\Test\TEST.mdf' is not a valid database
> file header. The PageAudit property is incorrect"

Any insights on this issue are highly appreciated.

Checked information about 5172 from below urls [here](https://www.sqlrecoverytool.com/fix-ms-sql-server-error-5172.html) and [here](https://bobcares.com/blog/sql-error-5172/).

Above all talks about fixing the solution.

Is there any way we can prevent this error?

Is 5172 can be caused due to RACE Conditions?

Comment: Is the `C:\Test` folder in your antivirus software's "Ignore Folders" list? Ref: [How to choose antivirus software to run on computers that are running SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/309422/choosing-antivirus-software-for-computers-that-run-sql-server)